# How to achieve a scroll effect similar to the Google Play Music app's album screen?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-animation

On the album screen of Google's Play Music app, the track list scrolls over the band picture as the image simultaneously slides under the action bar.

I want to do something similar where a list view is scrolled up and pushes the layout above it off screen. My focus here is only on pushing the view above the list view off the screen so that the list fills the screen as it scrolls.

What is the best way to approach this?

Here is a screen shot for reference after the track list has been scrolled up partially:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to use Manuel Peinado's [FadingActionBar](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar) library.